# Summation of a cubed logarithm of n.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, logarithms, exponentiation

I understand that by the property of

$ \log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab) $

we can derive

$\sum_{i=0}^n \log(i) = \log(n!) $

but how would I go about calculating

$\sum_{j=0}^{n^2} \log(j)^3 $ or $\sum_{j=0}^{n^2} \log(j)^3 - 1 $ ?

Comment: The last one is the same as the previous minus $n^2+1$

Comment: Your index should be starting from $1$ rather than $0$?

Comment: I don't know about you, but $\color{red}{\require{cancel}\cancelto\infty{\log(0)}}+\log(1)+\dots$ is a problem.

Comment: I assume you mean $\log(j)^3=\log(j)\log(j)\log(j)$?

Comment: I can solve $\log^2(j)$, but not $\log^3$

Comment: Yes, $ log(j)^3 = log(j)log(j)log(j) $ . I am trying to calculate the runtime of an algorithm which has two for loops and the second one's index is $ j = 0 $ , while its loop condition is $ j < log(n) * log(n) * log(n) $ .

Answer (score 1):

### Note that this is not a solution to the exact problem, but to a similar problem.

One can solve the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n\log^2(j)$.

Let $f(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\log^2(j)$ whenever $n\in\mathbb N$ so that we may have $f(n)=f(n-1)+\log^2(n)$

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+\log^2(n)$$

$$f'(n)=f'(n-1)+2\frac{\log(n)}n$$

$$f'(n)=f'(n-2)+2\left(\frac{\log(n-1)}{n-1}+\frac{\log(n)}n\right)$$

$$=f'(n-3)+2\left(\frac{\log(n-2)}{n-2}+\frac{\log(n-1)}{n-1}+\frac{\log(n)}n\right)\\\vdots\\f'(n)=f'(0)+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}k$$

[$$f'(n)=f'(0)-2\gamma_1+2\gamma_1^\star(n+1)$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+sum+ln(n)%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+m)

where $\gamma_1$ is a [Stieltjes constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html) and $\gamma_1^\star(n)$ is the [generalized Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Generalized_Stieltjes_constants).

Thus,

$$f(n)=\int_0^nf'(0)-2\gamma_1+2\gamma_1^\star(x+1)dx$$

> $$f(n)=f'(0)n-2\gamma_1n+\int_0^n\gamma_1^\star(x+1)dx$$

And if we let $n=1$,

$$0=f(1)=f'(0)-2\gamma_1+\int_0^1\gamma_1^\star(x+1)dx$$

> $$f'(0)=2\gamma_1-\int_0^1\gamma_1^\star(x+1)dx=c_1$$

Call it $c_1$ for simplicity.

$$f(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\log^2(j)=(c_1-2\gamma_1)n+\int_0^n\gamma_1^\star(x+1)dx$$